# can boost::process::system support bash commands separated by a semicolon?

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-process

Code:

```
#include <boost/system/process.hpp>  
int main() {  
  boost::process::system bp("echo foo; echo bar");  
}
```

Output:
foo; echo bar

Desired output:
foo
bar

I am receiving a string containing 1:MANY commands to run separated by a semi-colon; as one may run in in a shell terminal.  Is there a way to tell boost::process to interpret the string command as such?

Comment: Beware of the security implications of executing shell commands from untrusted sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd use an explicit bash:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0f705fee8808151)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::process;

int main() {
    bp::child c(
        bp::search_path("bash"),
        std::vector<std::string>{
            "-c", "echo foo; for a in {1..10}; do echo \"bar $a\"; done"});
    c.wait();
}
```

Prints

```
foo
bar 1
bar 2
bar 3
bar 4
bar 5
bar 6
bar 7
bar 8
bar 9
bar 10
```